# hive - how it works internally

Tags: hadoop, hive, metastore

For eg:

```
select * from <tablename> where <condition>  
select sum() from tablename where <condition>
```

basically filter, grouping, aggregation - it will generate MR Job and we will be able to see that in Resource Manager UI.

Lets say for eg:

```
show tables  
show database  
select * from tablename  
select count(*) from tablename  
Describe commands
```

These types of queries doesn't require MR jobs and will not show in RM, since this information are available in MetaStore as a properties.
Does hive logs some where? Can we identify those queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default hive stores logs in `/tmp/user` directory. But you can set this using `hive.querylog.location` property in hive-site.xml file.